# DataTables mostrar respuesta ajax en child

Tags: ajax, json, datatables

Necesito mostrar los datos de un resultado de AJAX en una tabla con el plugin DataTables al hacer click sobre cada fila.
Entiendo que debo hacerlo con los datos en formato JSON, pero no entiendo cómo incluir los datos en la tabla.
Aquí mi código.

```js
var tableSucursal =  $('#SucursalesTabla').DataTable(
  {
    responsive: true,
 rowReorder: true,
 "scrollX": true 
});


tableSucursal.rows().every( function interno(d) {
 
    this.child( '<table id="InternosTabla" width="100%"><thead><tr><th  class="id">Apellido</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Cargo</th><th>Tel&eacute;fono</th><th>M&oacute;vil</th><th colspan="2">E-mail</th><th>Observaciones</th><th align="center"><a id="AgregarInternos" style="cursor:pointer; display:none;" onclick="AgregarInternos();">Nuevo</a></tr></th>'+
 '</thead>'+
 '<tbody>'+
'<tr class="Internos">'+
'<td id="idintaut" class="idinterno" style="display:none;" data-campo="id_intaut">'+d.idintaut+'</td>'+
'<td id="intaut" class="" data-campo="apellido"><span></span></td>'+
'<td id="intaut" class="" data-campo="nombres"><span></span></td>'+
'<td id="intaut" class="" data-campo="cargo"><span></span></td>'+
'<td id="intaut" class="" data-campo="telfijo"><span></span></td>'+
'<td id="intaut" class="" data-campo="telmovil"><span></span></td>'+
'<td id="intaut" class="" data-campo="email" colspan="2"><span></span></td>'+
'<td id="intaut" class="" data-campo="observaciones"><span></span></td>'+
'<td id="intaut" class="" data-campo="ActivoNoActivo" align="center"><span></span></td>'+
'</tr>'+
 
 '</tbody>'+
 '</table>' 
 );
 

});


var tableInternos =  $('#InternosTabla').dataTable().api();

function datos(sucursal) {

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "clientes_showint.php",
  data: {sucursal:sucursal},
  dataType: "json",

  success: function(data){
  var $table = $('#InternosTabla').DataTable(); 
        $table.clear().rows.add(data);
        $table.draw();
  
  
  }
  });
} 

//Muestra u oculta los child. (Funciona bien)
$('#SucursalesTabla tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
 var tbody = $(this).closest('tbody');
 var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = tableSucursal.row( tr );

    var child = tableSucursal.row(this).child;
 var sucursal=$(this).closest("tr").find(".id").text();
 
    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        row.child.hide();
  
    }
    else {

 row.child.show();
 row.child(datos(sucursal)).show();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pero esos datos que quieres mostrar los quieres mostrar en un modal??? lo logico esque lo abrieras en un modal esa datatable y recogieras los datos

Esto es lo que yo hago.

```html
var obtener_data = function(tbody, table){
 $(tbody).on("click", "button.edit", function(){
  var data = table.row( $(this).parents("tr") ).data();
    
    ..........
  })
)
```

Comment: No es lo que buscaba, pero me gusta tu idea. La tomo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada compañero.